# PHP & AJAX - Error with json return

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, authentication

I'm having an issue with Login via PHP & AJAX.
When I click in Login Button, the Alert does not happen. It just redirects me to login.php and shows JSON return, like:
{"return":"error"} or {"return":"sucess"}

See the AJAX file:

```
 $('#button').bind('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "login.php",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {user: user, pass: pass},
        sucess: function(json){
            if(json.return== 'error') {
                alert("Login Error");
            } else if (json.return == 'sucess'){
                alert("Login ok!")
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and PHP file:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("lib/db.php");

header('Content-Type: application/json');
    if(isset($_POST['user'])) {

        if(isset($_POST['pass'])) {
            $user   = $_POST['user'];
            $pass       = $_POST['pass'];

            $conn = new CONECTION();

            $returnAuth = $conn->UserAutentication($user, $pass);
            $returnOk = array("return"=>"sucess");
            $returnError = array("return"=>"error");

            if(!$returnAuth[0]) {
                echo json_encode($returnError);
            } else {
                echo json_encode($returnOk);
            }

            $conn->Disconnect();
        }
    }
?>
```

What did I do wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it a submit button?

Comment: `sucess` needs to be `success`

Comment: Add return
Try this 
if(json.return== 'error') {
                alert("Login Error"); return;
            } else if (json.return == 'sucess'){
                alert("Login ok!"); return;
            }

Comment: If the problem doesn't solve with the fixing the typo in `sucess` try to add `error` scenario in ajax. It might be an error on PHP side.

Answer (score 0):

What does your HTML look like? I assume your button is a submit button in a form. Its default action is to submit the form using a normal request. You've got to prevent that from happening if you want to do only the AJAX request.

Your code should look like this:

```
$('#button').bind('click', function(event){

  // Prevent the default respons of the submit button, which is submitting the form.
  event.preventDefault();

  // Do your Ajax implementation instead: 
  $.ajax({
      url: "login.php",
      ...
```

See [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) in the jQuery api documentation.

This must be the cause. Javascript will not take you to another page unless you modify `window.location`, which you don't in your script. If your button is not a submit button, but a link, the same answer applies.

Answer (score 0):

When getting JSON  you need to parse it .

```
 obj = JSON.parse(json);

 if(obj.return== 'error') {
        alert("Login Error");

 } else if (obj.return == 'sucess'){
         alert("Login ok!");

  }
```

Comment: jQuery will do this for you if you set `dataType: "json"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use success instead of sucess or when success you need to parse json use $.parseJSON(your response);

Answer (score 0):

in my code `sucess` is correct.

I don't know why, but I fixed this issue serializing my form in the data option, see:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "login.php",
   type: "POST",
   cache: false,
   dataType: "json",
   data: $('#formAUTHUSER').serialize()
   ...
```

Thanks All.